# possible to show road-path-smooth items at lower zoom levels

Tags: mapbox

I'd like for my road-path-smooth elements to show at a lower zoom level than they currently are because my application is for the outdoors and these are more important elements.  Is that possible? I can't seem to find out how to adjust this in studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about displaying layers from the Mapbox Streets tileset, then no, it's probably not possible. The vector tiles are optimised for Mapbox's style (also, confusingly, called Mapbox Streets), and don't contain data that isn't already displayed.

Your need is a common one, but unfortunately the only way to solve it is to find a different set of vector tiles that meets your needs, or create one yourself.